# Not able to see Material-Ui Icon

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am trying to add an icons using Material-UI but facing this error -

```
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (bundle.js:60941:17)
    at useContext (bundle.js:60949:24)
    at bundle.js:57580:66
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:33800:22)
    at updateForwardRef (bundle.js:35822:24)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:37810:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:22750:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:22799:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:22859:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:42601:11)
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <MuiSvgIconRoot> component:

    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:57580:66
    at SvgIcon (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1493:82)
    at ExpandMoreIcon
    at div
    at div
    at sidebar
    at div
    at App
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45202:20)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
bootstrap:27 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (bundle.js:60941:17)
    at useContext (bundle.js:60949:24)
    at bundle.js:57580:66
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:33800:22)
    at updateForwardRef (bundle.js:35822:24)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:37810:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:22750:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:22799:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:22859:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:42601:11)
```

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51lcD.png)

I have also added a test and it is returning true in the console but still unable to see the icon on my screen

[A blank page is being returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Qxy.png)

Comment: can you provide your package.json content?

Comment: ```{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1"
  }
}
```

This is the package.json file